# SQLAlchemy ORM: Sum of products

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, greatest-n-per-group

Let's say I have a ROOMS table with width and length columns, and a corresponding SQLAlchemy model. Is there a clean and efficient way to get a total area of all rooms, i.e. sum(length x width)? It's easy enough to do by looping at the client but it must surely be more efficient if it can be fetched by a query at the server.

**Edit:**

I thought I was being helpful by reducing the problem to a simple, clean example but I now realise I was just shooting myself in the foot because my difficulties evidently stem from a more fundamental lack of understanding of SQLAlchemy and working with ORMs.

My model (flask-sqlalchemy) actually involves three related tables: holdings, commodities and prices. Commodities have many prices, and each holding is a quantity of a given commodity. I have it set up as follows:

```
class Holding(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    time = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP, index=True)
    quantity = db.Column(db.DECIMAL(10,5))
    commodity_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('commodity.id'))

    commodity = db.relationship('Commodity', back_populates='holdings')

class Commodity(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    symbol = db.Column(db.String(20))
    name = db.Column(db.String(150))

    holdings = db.relationship('Holding', back_populates='commodity', lazy='dynamic')
    prices = db.relationship('Price', back_populates='commodity', lazy='dynamic', order_by='Price.time.desc()')

class Price(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    time = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP, index=True)
    amount = db.Column(db.DECIMAL(10,5), index=True)
    commodity_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('commodity.id'))

    commodity = db.relationship('Commodity', back_populates='prices')
```

I want the sum of Holding.quantity * Holding.commodity.[most recent price].

Since Commodity.prices is in descending time order I can easily calculate the value in a Holding loop examining:

```
h.commodity.prices.first().amount * h.quantity
```

... but I can't see how to get at the related Price details from a single query, so I don't know how to apply @leovp's solution.

I hope that properly describes the problem now, apologies for the false start.

Comment: Suppose, suppose... so do you have a model or do you not?! And yes, this is possible. Just select the sum over the product.

Comment: No, I don't have that particular model - the ROOMS example was a simplification that I thought described the problem nicely. Clearly I don't know how to select the sum over the product.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä I can do it in raw SQL but I'd like to know how to do it the SQLAlchemy ORM way. Hopefully my updated description clarifies.

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: MySQL (version 5.7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more interesting part about your question is solving the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem. Now, I'm pretty green when it comes to MySQL, so there might be more efficient solutions to that than this:

```
In [43]: price_alias = db.aliased(Price)

In [44]: latest_price = db.session.query(Price.commodity_id, Price.amount).\
    ...:     outerjoin(price_alias,
    ...:               db.and_(price_alias.commodity_id == Price.commodity_id,
    ...:                       price_alias.time > Price.time)).\
    ...:     filter(price_alias.id == None).\
    ...:     subquery()
```

The self left join tries to join rows with greater *time*, which do not exist for the latest price, hence the `filter(price_alias.id == None)`.

What's left then is to just join `Holding`s with the subquery:

```
In [46]: sum_of_products = db.session.query(
    ...:         db.func.sum(Holding.quantity * latest_price.c.amount)).\
    ...:     join(latest_price,
    ...:          latest_price.c.commodity_id == Holding.commodity_id).\
    ...:     scalar()
```

Comment: Thank you, that works just fine. The self-join approach is what I'm currently using elsewhere in raw SQL. I'm new to SQLAlchemy (and Python for that matter) other than a quick look a few years ago and I was tying myself in knots trying to do anything more than straightforward queries with the ORM. Your solution is a little slower than raw SQL but that's to be expected with library overheads and it's still only small fractions of a second, which is plenty fast enough. I'll have to dissect it while poring over the SQLAlchemy documentation to try to get a better understanding of how it works!

Comment: If you're more familiar with raw SQL, you might benefit from [`Query.from_statement()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.from_statement) at times – if you want to combine raw SQL and querying ORM entities that is. And of course there's [`Session.execute()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.execute) for that odd query every now and then. The thing about SQLAlchemy is that it has layers. The ORM is built on top of the Core, which uses DB-API connections etc.

Comment: Session.execute() is what I've used so far, I'll take a look at Query.from_statement() - thanks for the tip. I'm much more familiar with SQL (though not exactly an expert) but I'd like to learn more about the ORM. That won't happen if I stay in my comfort zone by dropping down to SQL as soon as things get a bit complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your model is named Room and it has properties such as `length` and `width`:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
total_area = session.query(func.sum(Room.length * Room.width))
```

Which is going to be translated as something like that:

```
SELECT sum(rooms.length * rooms.width) AS sum_1 
FROM rooms
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've realised I'm struggling more than I thought - please see edit.